# ElasticSearch - Delete documents by specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

This seemingly simple task is not well-documented in the ElasticSearch documentation:

We have an ElasticSearch instance with an index that has a field in it called `sourceId`.  What API call would I make to first, `GET` all documents with 100 in the `sourceId` field (to verify the results before deletion) and then to `DELETE` same documents?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You probably need to make two API calls here. First to view the count of documents, second one to perform the deletion.

Query would be the same, however the end points are different. Also I'm assuming the `sourceId` would be of type `keyword`

### Query to Verify

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "sourceId": "100"
    }
  }
}
```

Execute the above [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and take a note at the `hits.total` of the response.

Remove the `"size":0` in the above query if you want to view the entire documents as response.

Once you have the details, you can go ahead and perform the deletion using the same query as shown in the below query, notice the endpoint though.

### Query to Delete

```
POST <your_index_name>/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "sourceId": "100"
    }
  }
}
```

Once you execute the [Deletion By Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html), notice the `deleted` field in the response. It must show you the same number.

I've used term queries however you can also make use of any [Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) or any complex [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Just make sure that the query is correct.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Kamal, thanks for your answer.  Actually sourceId type is long.  How does this change your answer?

Comment: @Stpete111 Technically it doesn't. Just don't need to make use of `double quotes` around `100`. Meaning it would be something like `"sourceId": 100`

Answer (score 3):

```
POST /my_index/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&pretty
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Delete all the documents of an index without deleting the mapping and settings:
See: https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/search-apis/elasticsearch-delete-by-query/